# jQueryUI Datepicker refresh after initialization

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

On site I have default datepicker initializated globally for all inputs with class `input-date`.

```
$('body').on('focus', '.input-date', function () {
  $(this).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: 'd.m.yy'
  });
});
```

But sometimes I need add some other options e.g. `minDate` for specific element. I already tried set this option and refresh it, but without success.

```
var dateField = $('#date');
dateField.datepicker('option', 'minDate', new Date());
dateField.datepicker('refresh');
```

So for now, only way how I managed to changed it it destroy it and create new one.

```
var dateField = $('#date');
dateField.datepicker('destroy');
dateField.datepicker(customOptions);
```

Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: are you sure you are referring the same element?  because I see first you initialize `'.input-date'` and then `'#date'`

Comment: seems fine here http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/28NWZ/1/

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it's same element. I just address it with `id` so other datepicker are not changed.

Comment: @s7anley is this similar to fiddle that Arun has created?  Seems to be working.

Comment: That is correct, but in my case I dont want to hook on some click event. Just want to change datepicker option.

Comment: Your are initializing the datepicker on focus, when do you think to set its properties? A button, on load, else?

Comment: Also on focus, but in javascript which is load later. That's my question, it's possible to update options.